# API works differently through browser URL

Tags: javascript, api

I have an API which when called through browser's URL downloads a .csv file. However, I cannot get the same behaviour when trying to call the above endpoint programmatically (e.g. by using `axios` library). Instead, I have used  `js-file-download` as to make it work:

```
let res = await axios.get(testUrl);
FileDownload(res.data, `report ${moment().format()}.csv`);
```

So, my question is why the latter works differently than the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of Ajax is that the response to the HTTP request is processed by *your JavaScript* instead of the browser's default handling.

So instead of being saved to the Downloads folder, the response is given to your JavaScript.